# liferay 7.1 PostgreSQL compatibility

Tags: postgresql, liferay-7.1

I'm looking for any information about official LF 7.1 CE support for PostgreSQL database. I have found information about compatibility for DXP edition:
https://web.liferay.com/services/support/compatibility-matrix 
but not for CE. So can I assume compatibilities from DXP are the same for CE edition?

Comment: My personal impression: Liferay does not really test on Postgres and it does not seem to be an important database platform for them. They apparently only test on MySQL and the commercial products. I regularly see beginner's mistakes with the migration code or simple SQL statements that assume that MySQL's non-standard SQL implementation works the same on other DBMS. I haven even seen issues related to Postgres errors in their Jira that were closed with "Works on MySQL"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'd be very interested in those issues and would like to bring them forward to the right people. Liferay's integration infrastructure actually tests on a matrix of different databases, application servers, etc - MySql is probably the most used platform, but we're even doing our system administration trainings on postgresql - it's not a neglected platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. you can assume them to be the same for the Open Source databases (DXP supports commercial databases as well, which CE doesn't. At least not out-of-the-box).

Of course there's the difference between "supports" and "support": Liferay CE will run on the same open source databases as DXP does, but "Support" in the sense of getting replies within an agreed service level is something different. Database support is robust though.